# Scroll to bottom of div after AJAX done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've seen here how to scroll to the bottom of a div...
But somehow it's not working for me...the same with autofocus.

Guess the problem is that I do an AJAX call, and it doesn't work.

My AJAX call:

```
  function toonBericht(vuserid) {
    $("#verstuurbericht").show();
    $("#chatresultaatcontent").val("");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: { userid:vuserid }, 
      url: './query/berichten/getbericht.php',
      success: function(result) {
        $("#chatresultaatcontent").html(result);
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatresultaatcontent");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
      }
    });
  }
```

Then ofcourse I have a div called #chatresultaatcontent.
It contains the chat messages that have been sent back and forth.

As an alternative I also tried loading a function (i.e. scrollBottom()) after success with the following code:

```
$("#chatresultaatcontent").scrollTop($("#chatresultaatcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
```

This also doesn't do anything. Same problem when trying to autofocus on a field after success...anybody know's why?

Comment: Does the element actually have a scrollbar, or are you confusing this with the windows scollbar ?

Comment: It has...however it uses the following CSS: overflow: auto; height: 350px;...so if it's more than 350px, a scrollbar appears (which happens in my example)

Comment: Just try `$("#chatresultaatcontent").html(result).scrollTop(1000);` and see if it's scrolls the element or not ?

Comment: Nope, it show the content, but doesn't scroll :(

Comment: Then you're probably targeting the wrong element.

Comment: @Nick did you try this on several browsers?

Comment: If I add a button myself and press it manually after my own function finished loading it does work. Somehow it hasn't completely finished loading and that's the reason it doesn't work. I got the right element...that's for sure. Uploading the code to jsfiddle will be very hard :(

Comment: Also, it's the same thing on Firefox or Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
success: function(result) {
    var content = $("#chatresultaatcontent");
    content .
        html(result).
        delay(50).
        scrollTop(content[0].scrollHeight);
        // The delay seems essential due to some strange problems
        // with the OP's code
  }
```

[A working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YL2gs/)

Comment: And what is `this` supposed to be in the scope of an ajax callback function, and `$(this)[0]` ??  Really!

Comment: I think it needs to be `$("#chatresultaatcontent")[0].scrollHeight`. Because scroll height is a standard JavaScript property not jQuery.

Comment: @adeneo : Yeah I've already fixed what you two have mentioned when preparing the Demo. It works now

Comment: Not working :( It does show the content...but won't scroll to the bottom

Comment: If I add a button myself and press it manually after my own function finished loading...it does work. But now to figure out how to get it done automatically...

Comment: @Nick I've edited the answer with a little delay between the two commands. Tell us if that works

Comment: At the same time I also used a delay and posted it here...it's indeed really strange. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the prettiest solution, but somehow this seems to work:

```
  function toonBericht(vuserid) {
    $("#verstuurbericht").show();
    $("#chatresultaatcontent").val("");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: { userid:vuserid }, 
      url: './query/chatten/getchatbericht.php',
      success: function(result) {
        $("#chatresultaatcontent").html(result);
        setTimeout(function(){
          var d = $("#chatresultaatcontent");
          d.scrollTop(d[0].scrollHeight);
        }, 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

Using a timeout of a microsecond? it does work...if I don't use that it doesn't. Pretty strange, but well...I'll just this solution for now.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't my programming style (my solution normally isn't either)...but I gave you an upvote. Again thanks for thinking with me

Comment: I don't like it that much either. You're probably loading a lot of data or something and it takes time for the browser to finish this action (I tried to reach such behavior but failed), and on the meanwhile the scrollHeight can't be calculated. There's still a place for debugging such as saving the `scrollHeight` at that moment and see what you get and also try to call `scrollTop` with an immediate number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chatresultaatcontent").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
```

Comment: Please explain the code.